# Subset data from the last time a condition is met till the last row of a data frame - applied to each subject

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID  TIME AMT  CONC
1    0   10   2 
1    1    0   1
1    5    20  15
1    10   0   30
1    12   0   16
```

I want to subset data for each subject ID, from the last time when AMT > 0 till the last row of the data frame for that individual.

output should be this:

```
ID  TIME AMT  CONC
1    5    20  15
1    10   0   30
1    12   0   16
```

I am using RStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `slice` and create a sequence between the max index where `AMT > 0` and the last index for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(max(which(AMT > 0)) : n())

#     ID  TIME   AMT  CONC
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     5    20    15
#2     1    10     0    30
#3     1    12     0    16
```

Comment: Yep, Great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(ind = cumsum(AMT > 0))  %>%
   filter(ind == max(ind), ind > 0) %>%
   select(-ind)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
#     ID  TIME   AMT  CONC
# <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     5    20    15
#2     1    10     0    30
#3     1    12     0    16
```

NOTE: This also works well when all the elements of 'AMT' is 0 for a particular group

```
df$ID[4:5] <- 2
df$AMT <- 0
df$AMT[4:5] <- c(1, 0)
```

---

Or another option is fewer steps

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() >= which.max(cumsum(AMT > 0)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), TIME = c(0L, 1L, 5L, 
10L, 12L), AMT = c(10L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L), CONC = c(2L, 1L, 15L, 
30L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```